# change url name via htaccess with possible conflict with another htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to change the URL from `localhost/cnew` to `localhost/new`.

I have the `.htaccess` file below inside my root directory `htdocs`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!/project1/mvc/public/).*) project1/mvc/public/$1 [L,NC]
```

This is the directory structure of my application.

```
htdocs
.htaccess
-project1
    -mvc
        -app
            -controllers
                cnew.php
        -public
            index.php
```

What should be the syntax for my `.htaccess` file and which directory should I put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert new rule before your other rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^cnew(/.*)?$ new$1 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!/project1/mvc/public/).*) project1/mvc/public/$1 [L,NC]
```